# In Clojure how can I make my own deftype refable?

Tags: clojure

I wish to make a clojure deftype which implements Clojure Hashmaps. I realise that I can implement the Clojure Interfaces to make my deftype Hashable and Sequable, but what do I need to include to get my deftype to play nice with the Clojure STM so that I can do:

```
(def a (ref (MyType.)))
```

and then to perform dosync operations such as conj and cons in an STM safe manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is allready solved by records they are what you describe a type/class but with interfaces like Hashable and Sequable (and more).

You can just put your record in a ref like anyother hashmap. Don't see the problem here.

Comment: I wanted extra functionality that hash table doesn't have, as in wanted persist to an external data store whenever things are added to the ref

Comment: Zubair, have you considered using agents for this?

Comment: Seams like I don't really understand the question, I think this would be good for the mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

`(def a (ref MyType))` doesn't make much sense because you are putting the class `MyType` in a ref.

The type that you put into a ref should ideally be an immutable type as the body of `dosync` should be free of side effects.

Comment: I amended the question. Sorry, I meant (MyType.)